# Paypal API Response Missing Fields

Tags: paypal

When calling `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` the SHIPTONAME and EMAIL fields are missing from the response. I know that SHIPTONAME is deprecated, but the replacement field is missing as well.  Full response below.

I can adjust for the missing name, but need the email for customer communications.

What would cause these fields to be missing from the response?

```
array(
  'TOKEN' => 'XXXXXX',
  'BILLINGAGREEMENTACCEPTEDSTATUS' => '0',
  'CHECKOUTSTATUS' => 'PaymentActionCompleted',
  'TIMESTAMP' => '2015-08-12T16:36:24Z',
  'CORRELATIONID' => 'XXXXXX',
  'ACK' => 'Success',
  'VERSION' => '113',
  'BUILD' => '000000',
  'PAYERID' => 'XXXXXXXX',
  'PAYERSTATUS' => 'verified',
  'COUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
  'SHIPTOSTREET' => 'XXXXXX',
  'SHIPTOCITY' => 'XXXXXX',
  'SHIPTOSTATE' => 'XX',
  'SHIPTOZIP' => 'XXXXX',
  'SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
  'SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME' => 'United States',
  'ADDRESSSTATUS' => 'Confirmed',
  'CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
  'AMT' => '27.90',
  'SHIPPINGAMT' => '0.00',
  'HANDLINGAMT' => '0.00',
  'TAXAMT' => '0.00',
  'NOTIFYURL' => 'https://xxxxx.xxx/xxx',
  'INSURANCEAMT' => '0.00',
  'SHIPDISCAMT' => '0.00',
  'TRANSACTIONID' => 'XXXXXX',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'USD',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => '27.90',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT' => '0.00',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT' => '0.00',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT' => '0.00',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL' => 'https://xxxxx.xxx/xxx',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INSURANCEAMT' => '0.00',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT' => '0.00',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TRANSACTIONID' => 'XXXXXX',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET' => 'XXXXXX',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY' => 'XXXXXX',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE' => 'XX',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP' => 'XXXXX',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE' => 'US',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYNAME' => 'United States',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ADDRESSSTATUS' => 'Confirmed',
  'PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_TRANSACTIONID' => 'XXXXX',
  'PAYMENTREQUESTINFO_0_ERRORCODE' => '0'
)
```

Comment: Is this happening with all orders or just one particular buyer?

Comment: The issue is very intermittent, so it appears to be isolated to specific buyers.

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue open with PayPal regarding this and they have acknowledged it as a bug. We suffer the same problems, once in a while the PayerId and any personal detail fields (email address etc) are omitted.

You need to take the correlation ID field that they would have returned to you from the faulty API call and ask them to investigate / open a ticket. That's the only way to get them to respond positively.

Saying that, this has been going on a while now and it is still not solved. But at least you know it's not just you.